# Postmates - webhook: determining the actual pickup_complete and delivered_complete

Tags: postmates

so I am looking into the postmates API and I have been able to create a delivery. This was great, I also setup a webhook url with ngrok to test the response from postmates but I am totally stumped as to how to determine when the pickup was actually completed and the dropoff/delivery was actually completed.

I saved all of the responses in a database and each time I did the test delivery, I received exactly 70 calls from the webhook endpoint. And each time 47 of them were in regards to the `'kind': 'event.delivery_status'`. Here are the stats:

#### THIS IS ALL IN TEST MODE WITH THE SANDBOX...

11 of those are `'status':'pickup_complete'`

14 of those are `'status':'pickup'`

11 of those are `'status':'dropoff'`

11 of those are `'status':'delivered'`

all of the webhook responses for `status=delivered` have a `'data.courier_imminent':false` value.

I went to the webpage for the `'data.tracking_url'` and when the webpage showed that the delivery was complete, I immediately updated the database to see how many records that I had saved and I was only at 32 total records. this means that the webhook was continuing to send me updates after it was supposedly complete.

Lastly, all of these statuses are not in order, they are totally random, in fact the 6th to last record that was received was a `pickup_complete` status..

#### The real question:

how will I know what is actually a `picked=completed`, `delivered=complete` etc..

Answer (score 1):

You'll receive a webhook of type `event.delivery_status`. One of the field within the body of the payload will be `{status: "delivered"}. This has been accurate so far. Postmates doesn't return a`delivered_at` timestamp, but you could create your own timestamp and store it along with the delivery for reporting.

As for the number of webhooks, Postmates has a delivery robot (called robo) that moves as if it was a real postmate. You'll receive a lot of webhooks of type `event.courier_update` with the updated location.